# Show attached files in mobile app: Screen vs Pop-up

Tags: mobile, lists, popup

We has a section in our mobile app that designed as user feedback service. And faced with question - how the best way to show user their attached files on screen with new form creation? User can attach maximum 10 files.

On our form we already use three input fields (two fields for choose only one value from several items and one for simple text input). Also one of fields for choose one value from several items we design to show this values inside popup because value has complex structure (not only title but also a little description for each item).

And then when we design a feature with optional attach files to our form - we faced with a question - how the best way to show already attached files to our user - continue to show it inside a popup at the same form screen (similar to our context with already used popup for one of our form filed) or using for this scenario separate screen?

Requirements for showing attached files:

1. Show a list of attached files;
2. Delete attached file;
3. Open attached file.
4. Back to screen with input form.

And also, does anyone know any examples of implementing a popup in mobile applications that provide a list items inside and support delete action for every item?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"does anyone know any examples of implementing a popup in mobile applications that provide a list items inside and support delete action for every item?"

A traditional popup on mobile is no place for a scrollable list because it results in bad UX: scrolling for lack of screen real estate while sacrificing valuable screen real estate just to provide context plus making it a little harder than usual to navigate away...however some modern alternatives exist such as the Chips/Pills pattern [1] which you could use in a BottomSheet that can be swiped to expand or shrink. Care should be taken to hint that there are more attachments than currently visible (if there are). That way the primary content is actually visible, the attachments take up a small amount of space and are secondary but can be accessed without limitations on display width plus minor limitations on display height. You may need to make the list of attachments itself scrollable, certainly if there is no limit to their amount.

[1] https://material.io/components/chips/